# how to re-arrange the numbers by the size of its first digit, second digit and so on?

Tags: python, list

i want to rearrange the list with the size of numbers' first digit, next second digit and so on..

for instance
if the list a is given below

```
a=[1,40,4]
```

i want to rearrange this list into

```
a=[4,40,1]
```

what i have tried was

```
b=[]
b += sorted(a, key=str)
b.reverse()
```

this process gives value of

```
b
[40,4,1]
```

This gives almost close to my need, but this algorithm considers 40 is bigger than 4

however i want 4 bigger than 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

a=[1,40,4,501,50,5]


l = []
for i in range(9,0,-1):
    l.append([x for x in a if int(str(x)[0])==i])
    
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([sorted(x) for x in l]))
```

Output

```
[5, 50, 501, 4, 40, 1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output for this case be `[5, 50, 501, 4, 40, 1]`?

Comment: Looks like i read the question wrong, i'll remove the reverse

Answer (score 1):

Found a key that'll work, though it's a bit convoluted:

```
a = [1, 40, 4]
b = list(
        reversed(
            sorted(a, key=lambda x:[(c, -len(str(x))) for c in str(x)]
            )
        )
    )
print(b)
# [4, 40, 1]
```

What we do, in the end, is to essentially use `str()` as a key, but then iterate through character-by-character and attach the negative length of the string. This ensures that, no matter what, longer numbers are sorted before shorter numbers with the same starting digits (thus, when reversed, they come after). For example, the sorting keys at play here:

```
1  -> [('1', '-1')]
40 -> [('4', '-2'), ('0', '-2')]
4  -> [('4', '-1')]
```

If you want to get rid of the call to `reversed()`, you can do this, basically the same logic but negative:

```
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x:[(-int(c), len(str(x))) for c in str(x)])
print(b)
# [4, 40, 1]
```